# Testing inputs of a string

Tags: java, input

```
public class QuizCheck
{
   /**
      Checks whether a string of quiz answers is valid. It must 
      contain an answer A, B, C, or D for each expected answer, or an 
      X to indicate that no answer was provided.
      @param input the answer string
      @param questions the number of questions in the string
      @return true if the string was valid, false otherwise
   */


public static boolean checkInputs(String input, int questions)
{
    boolean checkInputs;
    for (questions = 0; questions < input.Length(); counter--)
    {
        int letter = word.charAt(questions);
        if (letter == 'A' && letter == 'B' && letter == 'C' && letter == 'D' && letter == 'X')
        {
            checkInputs=true;

        } 
        else 
        {
           checkInputs=false;
        }
    }
    if(isInSet=true)
    {
       System.out.print("True");
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.print("False");
    }
}
```

My assignment is at the top and this is what I have. I can't get it to compile right now. I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: what is the compile error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that makes sense, and works (for your method only):

```
public static boolean checkInputs(String input, int questions)
{
    boolean checkInputs = true; // intially true, false if proven otherwise
    if (input.length() == questions) // if proper # of answers to # of questions
    {
        for (int question = 0; question < questions; question++)
        {
            int letter = input.charAt(question);
            if (!(letter == 'A' || letter == 'B' || letter == 'C' || letter == 'D' || letter == 'X'))
            {
                checkInputs = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // # of answers != # of questions, so return false
    }

    return checkInputs;
}
```

---

#### Your compile error

```
for (questions = 0; questions < input.Length(); counter--)
```

• You need to change `input.Length()` to `input.length()`

• You also use an undefined variable `counter`. You need to replace `counter--` with `questions++`

• If you kept it as `--`, you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error because you start at 0, and then go into the negatives, which you can't do for String positions.

• You were also not returning anything, even though your method needs to return a boolean.

I changed the

```
if(isInSet=true)
{
    System.out.print("True");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("False");
}
```

to `return checkInputs;`

• First of all, `isInSet` is not a variable you defined, so you would've needed to change that to `checkInputs`.
• Secondly, you originally didn't initialize `checkInputs`, so it would give you an error there too. Similarly when you return it, you need to have first initialized it. This is because there is a chance that it will never have a value if the for-loop breaks. It needs to have a definite value. So I changed `boolean checkInputs;` to `boolean checkInputs = true;`. That way, it will be true unless otherwise stated, which would be when any of the letters **don't** work for it. It will now always have a value of true or false.

• Your last compile error was `int letter = word.charAt(questions);` which is supposed to be 
`int letter = input.charAt(questions);`

---

#### Your logic

```
if(isInSet=true)
```

should be

```
if(isInSet==true)
```

You are supposed to be *comparing* a boolean value, not *setting* a boolean value.

and

```
if (letter == 'A' && letter == 'B' && letter == 'C' && letter == 'D' && letter == 'X')
```

should be

```
if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'B' || letter == 'C' || letter == 'D' || letter == 'X')
```

A letter can't be `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'D'` and `'X'`. If you want to test if the letter is any of them, use `||`: the OR logical operator, instead of `&&`: the AND logical operator.

But, what that if-structure should actually be is this:

```
if (!(letter == 'A' || letter == 'B' || letter == 'C' || letter == 'D' || letter == 'X'))
{
    checkInputs = false;
}
```

That way it will check if any of the letters DO NOT equal any of the accepted letters, and if that's the case, the input is invalid.

If you did it the opposite way, where it checked if any of the letter DO equal the excepted letters, then some could be valid and some could be invalid, and it would be more complicated to check for.

You weren't using your parameter `questions`. You were just changing it to be 0 right away in the for-loop. So first, check if there are as many answers in the `input` string as there were questions:

```
 if (input.length() == questions) {
     // test the letters
 } else {
     return false; }
```

Secondly, in your for-loop, create a new variable as the for-loop counter, and have it count from 0 to the number of questions:

```
for (int question = 0; question < questions; question++)
```

Comment: I fixed the logic errors, changed it to return instead of print. The only error I'm getting now is in the line int letter = word.charAt(questions);

Comment: @user3038538 change `word.charAt(questions);` to `input.charAt(questions);`

Comment: Thats what I did before I saw that you replied. It's compiling now. But when it runs I fail if a number is included in the string input.

Comment: @user3038538 give me a minute to fix that.

Comment: Okay, so after running the code at the top of the post the only error I'm getting is that it needs to return false if the parameter for input doesn't match the amount of questions.

Comment: @user3038538 now check.

Comment: Now its failing for some reason on the one with all the correct inputs and the right amount of letters to equal the questions.

Comment: Should there be a + 1 after str.length()

Comment: @user3038538 No; length gives you number of characters. The code will work, assuming all uppercase letters. For me, `QuizCheck.checkInputs("ABCDX", 5);` returns true. First, make sure your code is the same as my updated code. But copy your class to this site: http://pastie.org and click "create paste." Then send me the link to it.

Comment: Okay I got it to work. I didn't copy the whole code so i was leaving out the if (...) part which is why I was getting that error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3038538 please accept this answer, this is a very good and detailed explanation of every problem you had in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (letter == 'A' && letter == 'B' && letter == 'C' && letter == 'D' && letter == 'X')
```

A `letter` can't be 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and 'X' at the same time, so this expression is always `false`. Use `||` instead of `&&`.

You also have a problem with `isInSet` which you haven't used in the method at all. I think this is supposed to be

```
if(checkInputs)
```

Finally, you must `return` the value, not just print it. Your method is of type `boolean` so it must always either return one or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (questions = 0; questions < input.Length(); counter--)
```

is an endless loop

```
if (letter == 'A' && letter == 'B' && letter == 'C' && letter == 'D' && letter == 'X')
```

can never be true because a char can only be one char not 6 at a time
(maybe || as or ?)

```
if(isInSet=true)
```

what is isInSet?
also this should be isInSet == true or just isInSet

Answer (score 0):

First, the input can't be `'A'` *and* `'B'` *and*... The logic is incorrect.  You want the logical-OR operator:

```
if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'B' || ...
```

Second, when comparing to `true`, don't use the assignment operator, `=`.  Use `==` to compare values.

```
if (isInSet == true)
```

Or, because it's already a `boolean`:

```
if (isInSet)
```

Additionally, you've declared your method to return a `boolean`, but you aren't currently returning anything.  Return something -- probably the `checkInputs` value.

It's unclear where `isInSet` came from.  Is that really meant to be `checkInputs`?

Answer (score 0):

The skills you are lacking are following: Not correct operators used and wrong function type.
If we look at the function type you have typed boolean. That means it is suppose to return either true or false in the function.
If no return value exists it should be renamed to void instead which stands for not returning a value.
Instead of using the and operator ( && ) you shall use the or operator ( || ) because the and operator means if all expressions are true then execute the code.
the or operator executes the code if at least one expression is true which is the one you want to use.
if (isInSet=true) will execute all the time because the = operator assigns the value to the right to it.
So the only thing it checks is: If true is assigned to isInSet, execute the code below which will always make it true.

It should be if (isInSet == true). The == operator checks if the rightside is equal to the left side.